# Equivalent to top -ua

Tags: macos

In older version of Mac OS X, maybe up to 10.6 or something like that, you could use `top` with `-ua` which **a**ccumulated CPU-usage and listed the process with most CPU-time at the top. This combination has since disappeared and I have been unable to find a replacement. Any ideas?

A nice addition would be if you could tell it to accumulate CPU-hsitory for e.g., 10 seconds, 1 minute or so, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `top` has changed since 10.6 ([Here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/top/) is the man page for the `top` on Snow Leopard)

[Now](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html), to access to the accumulative mode you have to

- start `top`
- type <kbd>c</kbd> to change the current mode
- type <kbd>a</kbd> to set the accumulative mode (and enter to validate the input)

To sort by CPU time, use the `-o` option :  `top -o time`

About the second part of your question, I a bit curious. Accumulative mode counts the CPU time since the start of the mode. So I will do it for 10sec if you wait 10 seconds etc.

Comment: Regarding the second part I am interested in (1) a "floating accumulated" value, i.e., leaving top running in the background and everytime I looked at it I would see what had used most CPU time the last minute or something like that, or (2), start top and then it automatically quit after ten seconds leaving a list of the PIDs that had used most CPU during the session.

Comment: Are you sure about the sorting? I started top with -o time and then change the mode to accumulative. I then expected the process that had used the most CPU time since top was started to float to the top (sic!) but it does not seem to work like that.